# Is the value of a mined 5eth block significantly higher than 5eth on its own?

Tags: gas, block-reward

If I buy 5eth from a site like coinbase, I own 5eth and can spend it however. However, if I mine 5eth, I am entitled to the gas from transactions originating from the block.

Does this then mean that the value of mining a block (which is currently 5eth) is worth significantly more than the plain 5eth (assuming people continue to use eth and that I spend that 5eth)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 Eth is always 5 Eth

When mining a block, you earn the mining reward of 5 ETH + the gascost*gasprice of the transactions contained in the block. So overall you make more than 5 Eth.